# how to get the correspondent id automatically when inserting a record to a tabale

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I m developing staff records management system for a company using ROR3 I m new to ROR. Just started one month ago. So facing some troubles when developing the application.

these are some tables

1- profiles
id
service_number
first_name
last_name

2- promotions
id
service-number
rank
date_of_rank
profile_id

I have a form to insert promotion record when an employee promoted to next rank.

```
    <%= f.input :service_number %>
    <%= f.input :rank %>

    <%= f.input :date_of_rank, :start_year => Date.today.year - 50, :end_year => Date.today.year%>

        <%= f.hidden_field :profile_id %>


    <%= f.error :base %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

When inserting the data to the promotion table I want to insert profile_id correspondent to the service number entered by the user. profile_id is a hidden field for the user. So need to get the profile_id automatically. I m using service number because it is a unique number that company uses to identify the employees.

can anybody help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to have the `profile_id` hidden tag?  If `service_number` is a unique field, you can just look up the `Profile` based on that and associate it to the `Promotion` you are creating.

```
def create
  @promotion = Promotion.new(params[:promotion])
  profile = Profile.where(:service_number => @promotion.service_number).first
  @promotion.profile = profile  # this will set profile_id for you

  @promotion.save
  ...
end
```

That's assuming that your `Promotion` model has a `belongs_to :profile` association and your `Profile` model has a `has_many :promotions` association (or  `has_one :promotion`).